# Gamma function inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, special-functions, gamma-function

I'm new  to the gamma function and my current knowledge is that it's defined for all $z$ with $Re(z)>0$ by the integral

$$\Gamma(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt.$$

Recently, my little brother discovered the AM-GM inequality

$$\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}\geq (x_1x_2...x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

If $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2, ..., x_n = n$, the inequality can be rewritten to

$$n! \leq \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{n}.$$

For curiosity, I've decided to "extend" this inequality (maybe it's a famous one and I still don't know it). Here's my extension:

$$\Gamma(x+1) \leq \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{x}, \{x\in \mathbb{R}|x>-1\}$$

Using the site desmos.com, it's clear that the inequality is not valid at the interval $[0,1]$ (as can be seen in the figure).

[image: Inequality graph analysis]

So I think that the following is true:

$$
\boxed{\begin{array}_\Gamma(x+1)\leq \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{x}, \{x\in \mathbb{R}|-1<x\leq 0\,\cup\,x\geq1\}\\ \Gamma(x+1)\geq \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{x}, \{x\in \mathbb{R}|0\leq x\leq 1\}\end{array}}
$$

I'm not good with inequalities, so I've decided to ask here: Can I prove the statement (if it's really true)? If so, how?

Thank you in advance. Really appreciate your attention.

Comment: I added two points in the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\boxed{\begin{array}_\Gamma(x+1)\leq \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{x}, \{x\in \mathbb{R}|-1<x\leq 0\,\cup\,x\geq1\}\\ \Gamma(x+1)\geq \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{x}, \{x\in \mathbb{R}|0\leq x\leq 1\}\end{array}}$$

**Proof**:

We use the integral representation of $\ln\Gamma(x+1)$:
$$\ln\Gamma(x+1) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\left(x\mathrm{e}^{-t} + \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t(x+1)} - \mathrm{e}^{-t}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t. \tag{1}$$
(See: https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/LogGamma/07/01/01/.)

Using the known identity
$$\ln u = \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t} - \mathrm{e}^{-ut}}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t,$$
we have
$$x\ln\frac{x+1}{2}
= \int_0^\infty x\cdot \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t} - \mathrm{e}^{-(x+1)t/2}}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t. \tag{2}$$

Using (1) and (2), we have
\begin{align*}
 &\ln\Gamma(x + 1)- x\ln \frac{x+1}{2}\\[6pt]
 =\,& \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t(x+1)} - \mathrm{e}^{-t}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}} + x\mathrm{e}^{-(x+1)t/2}\right)\,\mathrm{d} t\\[6pt]
 =\,&\int_0^\infty x\cdot \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t}\mathrm{e}^{-xt/2}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}}\left(
 \mathrm{e}^{t/2}\cdot \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}}{t} - \mathrm{e}^{xt/2}\cdot \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-xt}}{xt}\right)\,\mathrm{d} t. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Let
$$f(u) := \mathrm{e}^{u/2}\cdot \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-u}}{u}.$$
It is easy to prove that $f(u)$ is strictly decreasing on $[-1, 0)$,
and strictly increasing on $(0, \infty)$.
Thus, we have
$$\mathrm{e}^{t/2}\cdot \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}}{t} - \mathrm{e}^{xt/2}\cdot \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-xt}}{xt} \ge 0, \quad \forall t > 0, ~\forall x \in (-1, 0)\cup (0, 1]$$
and
$$\mathrm{e}^{t/2}\cdot \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}}{t} - \mathrm{e}^{xt/2}\cdot \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-xt}}{xt} \le 0, \quad \forall t > 0, ~ \forall x \ge 1.$$

From (3), the desired results follow.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you! Really great answer. Can I ask you for a link or paper that contains the proof of the log gamma integral? Or it's just Binet's formula after some manipulation?

Comment: @otreblig You may find it in the book "A Course of Modern Analysis" by E. T. Whittaker and G. N. Watson, Chapter "gamma function".

Answer (score 3):

If we consider the function $$f(x)=\Gamma(x+1) - \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{x}$$ we have

- $f(0)=0$  $$f'(0)=\log (2)-\gamma>0\qquad  f''(0)=-2+\gamma ^2+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\log ^2(2)<0$$
- $f(1)=0$  $$ f'(1)=\frac{1}{2}-\gamma<0\qquad  f''(1)=-1-2 \gamma +\gamma ^2+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}<0$$

All of the above make that there is a maximum somewhere between $0$ and $1$ and it is positive. This make your conjecture perfectly correct.

**Edit**

If we approximate
$$f(x)=x(1-x)(a x+b)$$ and adjust $(a,b)$ in order to match the derivatives at $x=0$ and $x=1$, we have
$$a=-\frac{1}{2}+2 \gamma -\log (2) \qquad\qquad b=\log (2)-\gamma$$

The maximum of $g(x)$ accurs at $x_*=0.4513$ which is not bad since the maximum of $f(x)$ accurs at $x_*=0.4479$.

Similarly, the maximum value of $g(x)$ is $0.0244$ while the maximum value of $f(x)$ is $0.0204$

Comment: Hi Claude. Thank you for this solution. It's great. I'm still wondering if there is an approach that does not require first and second derivatives (maybe just some inequalities).

Comment: @otreblig I think this is not enough to prove that $f(x) \ge 0$ on $[0, 1]$. For example, consider $g(x) = x(1-x)(8x^2-9x+2)$. We have $g(0) = 0, g'(0) > 0, g''(0) < 0$ and $g(1) = 0, g'(1) < 0, g''(1) < 0$. However $g(1/2) < 0$.